# AppDelegate not used when scenes configured in Info.plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, mac-catalyst, uiscene

I have an old (Objective-C) iOS app that I expanded to Mac Catalyst, and now I want to add multi-window support to the Mac version, without affecting the iOS version. In accordance with several tutorials ([example](https://fleetingpixels.com/blog/2020/6/17/how-to-adopt-uiscene-apis-in-an-existing-ios-project)), I've set up a `SceneDelegate` like this...

```
@implementation SceneDelegate

#if TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST

@synthesize window;

- (void)scene:(UIScene *)scene willConnectToSession:(UISceneSession *)session options:(UISceneConnectionOptions *)connectionOptions {
    if ([scene isKindOfClass:[UIWindowScene class]]) {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithWindowScene:(UIWindowScene *)scene];
        self.window.rootViewController = [[MainView alloc] init];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
}

@end

#endif
```

...added this to AppDelegate...

```
#if TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST

- (UISceneConfiguration *)application:(UIApplication *)application configurationForConnectingSceneSession:(nonnull UISceneSession *)connectingSceneSession options:(nonnull UISceneConnectionOptions *)options {
    return [[UISceneConfiguration alloc] initWithName:@"Main" sessionRole:connectingSceneSession.role];
}

#endif
```

...and added this to Info.plist:

```
<key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
<dict>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
<key>UIApplicationSceneManifest-macos</key>
<dict>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                <string>Main</string>
                <key>UISceneClassName</key>
                <string>UIWindowScene</string>
                <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                <string>SceneDelegate</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I'm still doing a lot of setup in the `AppDelegate`'s `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, but that method was never called, nor was `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession:options:`, and there were no errors in the console. So I moved the definition of the scene from the Info.plist file to the `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession:options:` method, like this...

```
- (UISceneConfiguration *)application:(UIApplication *)application configurationForConnectingSceneSession:(nonnull UISceneSession *)connectingSceneSession options:(nonnull UISceneConnectionOptions *)options {
    UISceneConfiguration *config = [[UISceneConfiguration alloc] initWithName:@"Main" sessionRole:UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication];
    config.sceneClass = [UIWindowScene class];
    config.delegateClass = [SceneDelegate class];
    return config;
}
```

...leaving only this in Info.plist:

```
<key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
<dict>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
<key>UIApplicationSceneManifest-macos</key>
<dict>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Now it works as expected.

Is defining the scene configurations in Info.plist supposed to completely bypass the `AppDelegate`? Based on the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/3197905-application), it seems like maybe that's supposed to bypass `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession:options:`, but I haven't seen any indication that it should also bypass `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. [Some tutorials](https://medium.com/@kalyan.parise/understanding-scene-delegate-app-delegate-7503d48c5445) explicitly say that method should still run.

I tried removing the `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession:options:` method in case defining the configurations in two places was confusing the SDK, but `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` was still not called, as long as `UISceneConfigurations` was in Info.plist.

I can tell whether `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is called or not by adding a breakpoint to its first line. The breakpoint gets hit unless I add the `UISceneConfigurations` dictionary to the Info.plist, but making only that change causes the breakpoint to not get hit.